# Run tracking code after validation but before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

There is form. Validation function is attached to submit event and it returns true/false ($(form).submit(...)).

```
<form name="f" class="form">
<input type=text name=ff>
</form>

$(".form").submit(function() {
  if ($("[name='ff']").val()==="") {
    return false
  }
  return true;
})
```

We want to run some tracking script that must be executed in case if validation return true but without changing original validation function (We have possibility to enable/disable tracking script from interface)

```
  var _this = this;
  ga('send', 'pageview', 'la-la-la', {
    'hitCallback': function() {
        jQuery(_this).parents('form').first().submit();
    }
  })
  return !window.ga;
```

How would I do that properly?

So far I want to unbind current submit/validation function and bind my function and inside of it execute validation logic and then run my tracking code. In such way I can easy disable/enable tracking code without interrupting original behavior of logic.

However I have issues in doing this. Please advise. I want to do something like that

```
var fn = $(.form).submit // get attached logic - and that's does not work
$(.form).unbind('submit') // unbind it from submit
$(.form).submit(function() { // attach my code and reuse old code inside
  my code...
  if (fn()===true) {
    my code...
  }
  my code...
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made solution using hitCallback event

```
jQuery(".register-form").on("valid", function(f) {
  var event = "/signup";

  var _this = this;
  ga('send', 'pageview', event, {
    'hitCallback': function() {
      _this.submit();
    }
  })
  return !(ga.hasOwnProperty('loaded') && ga.loaded === true);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following code 
`$(form).on("submit", function(f){
//your function here. lets say you add a counter that starts from 0 and your validation functon returns its count. then you would say 
if (counter != 0){ f.preventDefault(); } //this would stop the form from submitting until a condition on your function is met
});`

Comment: It does not work (or I do something wrong).
I've updated posts maybe it will help to describe my problem a bit more.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand correctly your issue, but you should use something like this:  $(form).on("submit", function(f){
   ga('send', 'pageview', 'la-la-la', {
     'hitCallback': function() {
         if (//callback not successful){
          f.preventDefault() <-- this should prevent the form from submitting if the callback returns false
         }
     }
  })
  });

Comment: I have added the logic what I really want to do
- get current validation logic from form;
- unbind it from submit
- bind new logic I wrote and reuse old logic inside of new logic.

Comment: with this var fn = $(.form).submit you are trying to add a listener to an event. it should be $("form").submit(). Then you are unbiding the submit and trying to listen again for the submit (thats how your code reads to me). What you should do is use the $("form").on("submit", function(f){});. which will listen for the submit, and will be able to prevent it when matched with an attribute.